# Insert Rows based on a Cell value and fill down

Tags: excel, vba, insert, rows

I currently have a sheet with values that look like this, as an example:

```
1 A     B     C     D..............
2 1     Title of item 1
3       Formulas and formatting 1
4 2     Title of item 2
5       Formulas and formatting 2
6 3     Title of item 3
7       Formulas and formatting 3
```

What i want to happen is that the code looks up column A. If column A contains a number > 1 then it inserts that number (-1) rows, but 2 rows down. I then need it fill the formulas (the formulas need to be dragged down) and formats down from the row above to the last row inserted for that section. So it would look something like this:

```
1 A     B     C     D...............
2 1     Title of item 1
3       Formulas and formatting 1
4 2     Title of item 2
5       Formulas and formatting 2
6       Formulas and formatting 2
7 3     Title of item 3
8       Formulas and formatting 3
9       Formulas and formatting 3
10      Formulas and formatting 3
```

And so on and so.... Note, it needs to drag the entire row formulas and foramts, not just A-D...

I think I am almost there with the following code, but I can't get it to fill down from the first row with formulas, under the value in A, until the last row inserted for that section....

Here's my code:

```
Sub Add_Rows()
  Dim r As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "A").Value > 1 Then Rows(r + 2).Resize(Cells(r, "A").Value - 1).Insert

  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If any one could help me with the above that would be amazing!! Equally, I think my method might be a bit clumsy, so I am open to more eloquent solutions too!! Thanks Guys, this forum has saved my skin so many times!!! One day I hope I will get to a point where I can maybe answer some questions instead of always asking them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You're not actually copying and pasting anything.

```
Sub Add_Rows()

  Dim r As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, "A")) Then
        If Cells(r, "A").Value > 1 Then
            Rows(r + 2).Resize(Cells(r, "A").Value - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Rows(r + 1).Copy
            Rows(r + 2).Resize(Cells(r, "A").Value - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    End If
  Next r

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.Goto Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks @SJR - I was trying the `Shift:=xlDown` but just seem to get it to work - just one comment - after the macro has ran, it is still highlighting the last rows that it pasted and also the last row that it copied - anyway of cleanly finishing the action, so that nothing it highlighted?

Comment: You can add this at the end to turn off the 'marching ants' `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. The only way to stop the row being highlighted would be to select another cell - something always has to be selected.

Comment: Right okay - I wasn't aware that something must always be highlighted - the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` didn't work, but thanks anyway. I also get a `Run time error '13' - Type Mismatch` when I run the macro in my sheet and it highlights the following line of code `Rows(r + 2).Resize(Cells(r, "A").Value - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown`. It still performs what I want, but not without doing that first..... Other than that, it seems do be doing exactly what I need!

Comment: Probably the cell doesn't contain a number.

Comment: Correct, though it didn't do that on my test sheet that had blank cells. I do have cells in column A with text though.... could this be it?

Comment: Yes because you can't resize by a string. I've added a check in the code above to avoid this error.

Comment: Question @SJR. Could I add some complexity to it? I only what it to have the number of rows in the cell i.e if the value changes from 3 to 2, I want it to remove the bottom row from that section - then if it goes to 5 only have 5 rows (as opposed to 7 as it would do now.....).Does that make sense? and is it possible?